# NSDate issue with UTC Offset and Time Zones

Tags: date, timezone, nsdate, offset, utc

I am pulling a date from a server in ISO 8601 format. The date represents the time a specific episode of a specific show airs. Here is an example date:

"2013-07-30T21:00:00-05:00"

That is July 30th, 2013 at 9:00PM EST. EST being -05:00. The problem comes in when I try and display the date back to the user(myself in this case). I am currently in central time but daylight savings time is active. Which means iOS says that I am currently in Central Daylight Time which is also -05:00(normal CST is -06:00).

This show airs in my CST time zone at 8:00PM. It doesn't matter if daylight savings time is on or off, the show always airs whenever the clock hits 8:00PM. Normally if I wasn't in daylight savings time iOS would be able to do the proper conversions as it would be moving from -05:00 to -06:00. SInce I am currently in daylight savings time though it sees -05:00 as the original offset and -05:00 as my current offset so it does no conversion and displays the show starting at 9:00PM. Any idea how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to map just a *time zone offset* like `-05:00` back to an actual *time zone* like Central Time or Eastern Time.  As you pointed out, it could be Central Daylight Time, or Eastern Standard Time.  However, it could be any number of other time zones that happen to use a `-05:00` offset at one point or another.  See [this list of time zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) and sort by one of the offset columns so you can get an idea of how many their are.  You can also [look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9205:00).

Now fortunately, you have another piece of information - the date/time.  So you can use this to partially distinguish between *some* of these zones.  You also may be able to further limit the ambiguities if you know for certain that your data is the USA.

There is still one problem though.  A time like `2013-11-03T01:00:00-05:00` is actually in *both* CDT and EST simultaneously!  How can that be?  Well, in the USA we do not all change our clocks at the same moment.  Each time zone changes it at 2AM in their own local time.  So there is one hour every year that Eastern time has already encountered their fall-back transition, but Central time hasn't yet.

The only real way to deal with all of this is to store some other bit of context information, such as the full IANA time zone (`America/New_York` for Eastern or `America/Chicago` for Central, etc.) - or if it's just for display then you can store a string with the time zone abbreviation of your choosing (EST, CDT, etc.).

See also:  "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).